# MySQL sequential inserts are slow while threaded inserts are fast - why?

Tags: mysql, performance, go, goroutine

I found that sequentially inserting data into my database is very slow compared to a multi-threaded solution where both insert the same number of rows.
Inserting 50000 rows took ~4 mins in my sequential approach and only ~10 seconds with the parallel version.

I use the https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql driver.
For the database, I just took the recent version of XAMPP for windows and use the MySQL database with its standard config.

sequential version:

```
for i := 0; i < 50000; i++ {

        _, err2 := db.Exec("insert into testtable (num, text1, text2) values (?, ?, ?)", i, "txt1", "txt2")

        if err2 != nil {
            fmt.Println(err2)
        }

}
```

Parallel version:

```
for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := 0; j < 1000; j++ {
                _, err2 := db.Exec("insert into testtable (num, text1, text2) values (?, ?, ?)", 1, "txt1", "txt2")
                if err2 != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err2)
                }
            }
        }()
}
```

Why is the first one so slow compared to the second version?
Any Ideas? Am I maybe using the wrong function for inserting data?

Comment: @armmie are you asking why the sequential version takes ~4 minutes? Or are you asking why, in general, code executed concurrently is "faster" than code executed sequentially?

Comment: *"MySQL sequential inserts are slow while threaded inserts are fast - why?"* @armmie I would ask "why not?". Why would you expect sequential code to perform the same as parallel code? What is the purpose of parallel code if not to provide better performance than that of sequential code?

Comment: I assumed that the database will handle the inserts to the same table sequentially anyways and therefore did not expect a difference in performance.
That's why I am surprised.

Comment: @armmie that might have been the case if `db` represented a single connection, however the `*sql.DB` type is a connection *pool* designed for concurrent use, so while your sequential code, because it is sequential, is only utilizing a single connection from the pool, the concurrent code is utilizing as many connections as the mysql server allows and the pool can manage.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB *"DB is a database handle representing a pool of zero or more underlying connections. It's safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines."*

Comment: Ohhh, so the runtime automatically creates more connections. I thought it will just serialize the concurrent inserts into the same connection since they all got the same db reference. Thank you for your help!! :)

Comment: But the risk of parallel execution is all the locks and mutexes that prevent collisions on memory usage, indexes, etc, etc.  Still, parallel _should_ be faster than sequential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of overhead in running an `INSERT`:

- Communication between client and server.
- Parse the `INSERT`
- Open the table, etc.
- Get next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value.
- Check for conflicts, deadlocks, etc.
- Commit the transaction.

And all of that is done in a single CPU, with waiting for I/O, if necessary.

You have 50 threads; they ran 24 times as fast.

But you can do 10 times as good as that -- Batch up the rows into a single `INSERT` 100 rows at a time.  This eliminates much of the overhead, especially the commit.  (Going past 100-1000 rows is getting into diminishing returns and other overheads; so stop there.)

Meanwhile, don't use more threads than, say, twice the number of CPU cores you have.  Otherwise, they will just stumble over each other.  The *may* be why 50 threads was *only* 24 times as fast.